# Prove or disprove: Let $V$ be a vector space, and $T:V\to V$ a diagonalizable linear operator...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

then $Ker(T)=ker(T^{2018})$. 

My Work: 
My thoughts are a little bit shattered, but here's what I tried to do, I wanted to prove it by proving $Ker(T)\subset ker(T^{2018})$ and $Ker(T^{2018})\subset ker(T)$. 
I started the first direction: $Ker(T)\subset ker(T^{2018})$. Let $v\in Ker(T)$, then $T(v)=0$, and it's known that $T(0)=0$ in any linear transformation, so $T(T(v))=T(0)=0$, so $T^{2018}=T(....T(v))=T(0)=0$ so $v \in ker(T^{2018})$. 
I'm struggling to prove the second direction, and I don't feel alright with my proof up as I feel like I could have shown my idea in a better way. 
But from the given information that $T$ is diagonalizable, I tried to do this: there exists a basis $B$ such that $[T]_B$ is diagonal. Here I'm trying to link between $T$ and $T^{2018}$ but I'm not really getting how to do it. 
 Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675574/diagonalizable-linear-operator-is-kert-kert2?rq=1

Comment: Hint: Since $T$ is diagonalisable, there exists a basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ such that $T$ is diagonal with respect to this matrix. Can you describe what $T^{2018}$ does to $e_1,\ldots,e_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is diagonalizable there exists $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ basis of $V$ and $\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $T(v_i)=\lambda_i v_i, i=1,\cdots, n.$

Thus if $v=\sum_i \alpha_i v_i$ then

$$T(v)=T\left(\sum_i \alpha_i v_i\right)=\sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i v_i$$ and

$$T^{2018}(v)=T^{2018}\left(\sum_i \alpha_i v_i\right)=\sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i^{2018} v_i.$$

Thus we have that

\begin{align}
v\in Ker (T^{2018}) & \iff \sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i^{2018} v_i=0 \\ & \iff \alpha_i \lambda_i^{2018}=0, \forall i \\ & \iff \alpha_i \lambda_i=0, \forall i \\ & \iff \sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i v_i=0 \\ & \iff v\in Ker (T).
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate the hint, I think I started getting the idea, but not sure if I got it well, so $T^{2018}$ has eigenvalues that are the same as $T$ but to the power $2018$, to link this to kernels, if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then it stays $0$ as an eigen value for $T^{2018}$, I know that the basis of $kerT$ is the basis of the eigen space of $0$, I didn't quite know how to move on from here to finish the proof

Comment: You are on the right way. I have completed the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, this really helps, I appreciate the help :).